# pass array of specific size to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have an array of size 4096 in a program and after a certain stage of program, this array is no longer required. Meanwhile, I get different set of measurement data's from the application. Instead of creating so many arrays, I reuse the same array to save memory space for the application. I store different measurement data's of smaller sizes (e.g.: 64) in the array mentioned above.

Example:
The purpose of *double bigArray[4096]* is done and this array is reused in later part of program to store other measured values.

- measured data 1 of size 64 stored in bigArray[0 to 63]
- measured data 2 of size 64 stored in bigArray[64 to 127]
- measured data 3 of size 64 stored in bigArray[128 to 191]

Now I need to pass values to other function as shown below:

```
void main()
{
  xyzFunction(bigArray[0:63], bigArray[64:127], bigArray[128:191]);
}

void xyzFunction(double *data1, double *data2, double *data3)
{
  ...calculations involving data1, data2, data3...
}
```

data1 should point only to first 64 array elements, and so on. I tried but could not exactly pass a part of data from bigArray to the function.

Any help to accomplish this is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't make a pointer to only the 64 first elements since a pointer only points to *one* element, but you can choose which one it points to: `(&bigArray[0], &bigArray[64], &bigArray[128])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a size parameter, like this

```
void xyzFunction(double *data1, size_t data1size, 
    double *data2, size_t data2size, double *data3, size_t data3size)
{
  /* ...calculations involving data1, data2, data3... */
}
```

and just call it like this

```
xyzFunction(bigArray, 64, bigArray + 64, 64, bigArray + 128, 64);
```

Oh, by the way, this is equivalent to @[molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074293/pass-array-of-specific-size-to-a-function-in-c/31074363#comment50167351_31074293)'s comment, except that you should pass the size, unless it's always the same.

Comment: or equivalently, `xyzFunction(&bigArray[0], 64, &bigArray [64], 64, &bigArray[128], 64);`

Comment: @user3528438 Yes, that's why I added a reference to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31074293/pass-array-of-specific-size-to-a-function-in-c/31074363#comment50167351_31074293).

Comment: No. In comment there is only addresses are passed.

Comment: Yes and in the reference to the comment, I said _except that ..._.